Salesforce Mobile SDK Hybrid local app and Experience Cloud user login problem
I followed every step to connect using Salesforce SDK mobile hybrid local app.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/mobile-sdk/guide/communities-mobilesdk.html
but when I try to connect using experience cloud login to my app. When I give the right username and password. it display a white screen and come back to the login screen.
When I see the user connection history in setup I see a login success.
Did someone had the same problem, maybe an experience cloud setup problem. I wasn't the one to setup it.

@Christian
Need to be recheck:

clean cache memory of your App. #reStart 

I believe, it's web login Authentication.

Recheck the login Url of portal user.

CSP (Content Security Policy) Policies: If your Experience Cloud site has restrictive CSP policies, it might prevent certain resources from loading properly in your mobile app, resulting in a white screen. Ensure that your CSP policies allow necessary resources to load.

OAuth Configuration: Double-check that your OAuth configuration in Salesforce is set up correctly for the mobile app. Ensure that the Redirect URI configured in Salesforce matches the one specified in your mobile app's configuration.

Session Settings: Check the session settings in your Salesforce org. If session settings are too restrictive, it might cause issues with maintaining the session between the mobile app and Salesforce.

Mobile SDK Configuration: Review the configuration in your mobile app to ensure that it's correctly configured to connect to your Experience Cloud site. Check if there are any errors in the configuration files (e.g., bootconfig.json, salesforcehybrid.json).

Network Issues: Ensure that there are no network issues preventing the mobile app from communicating with Salesforce. Check if there are any firewall rules or network restrictions causing communication problems.

Error Logging: Implement error logging in your mobile app to capture any errors that occur during the login process. This can help identify the root cause of the issue.


hope it's work.

Hi! It wasn't our community configuration and it was the problem. Thanks for the help.
